# Luhns Algorithm (Credit Card Validation)

Tags: python

```
def credit_card_validation(num):
    number = list(int(x) for x in str(num))
    number.reverse()
    for i in range(0,len(number)):
        if i%2 == 1:
            product = 2*(number[i])
            total_1 = 0 
            if product>9:
                total_1 = total_1 + product -9
            else:
                total_1 = total_1 + product
        else:
            total_2 = 0
            total_2 = total_2 + number[i] 
    if (total_1+total_2)%10 == 0:
        status = 'Valid'
    else:
        status = 'Invalid'
    return (status)
```

This is my code for the luhns algorithm. When I enter a valid credit card number, I get the output as invalid. Anyone can help me and tell me whats wrong in my code?

Comment: I'm not sure it's intended to reset total_1 or total_2 each time you use one of them ?

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to convert the number to be checked into a string as you can work directly on the number (expressed as an integer). Here's a little utility class that you may find helpful. The *isvalid* function executes in 3e-6 seconds on my machine.

```
class luhn():
    __map = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9]

    @staticmethod
    def __sumdigits(v, p=0):
        sum_ = 0
        while v > 0:
            d = v % 10
            sum_ += luhn.__map[d] if p else d
            p ^= 1
            v //= 10
        return sum_

    @staticmethod
    def isvalid(v):
        return luhn.__sumdigits(v) % 10 == 0

    @staticmethod
    def checkdigit(v):
        return 10 - luhn.__sumdigits(v, 1) % 10

print(luhn.isvalid(4447438549617137))
```